# Weird image after computing cvIntegral?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to understand the use of cvIntegral. Does the output image behave like the image as attached? Yah, when manually calculated the left top part does have small value (black) and as it goes to bottom right (brighter). Without normalization (0-255), the image is completely white and then some black.

[image: original image]

original image

[image: Integral Image]

Integral Image Normalize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it depends on which type of integral you want to calculate because there are three types of them - from [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#integral):

> The function calculates one or more integral images for the source
>   image as following: [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

If you talk about *first type of integral* than this is just sum of all pixels in rectangle `[(0,0),(x,y)]`. My output of integral image was this:
[image]

What seems to be logically correct.

With normalization (`255/max`) I see the same image as your output.

**Update:**
It seems that I get your error - `imwrite` looses quality of image (maybe) because some values of integrated image are too big (bigger than 255), but `imshow` shows it normally (that image was just a screenshot). So just use normalization as you did. Here's code:

```
Mat src = imread("moon.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat int1, norm;

integral(src, int1);

double max;
minMaxIdx(int1, 0, &max);
int1.convertTo(norm, CV_8UC1, 255/max);

imshow("simple output", int1);//shows normally
imshow("normalized output", norm);
//imwrite("output.jpg", int1);// looses quality
waitKey();
```

Comment: I don't get the output as yours. I know how it works actually. Just want to clarify if there is something wrong with the results I got.

Comment: cvMinMaxLoc(integralImg, &min_val, &max_val); cvConvertScale(integralImg, integralImg1, 255.0/max_val, 0);

Comment: So basically you got the same image as I have Astor?

Comment: From function `imwrite` - yes.

Comment: I feel that the normalize output is slightly different from yours after testing it. I'm using old opecv api.

Comment: Yes, `norm` and `int1` (from my code) are different images. My normalized image (`norm`) is the same as yours (from your question).

Comment: Astor, see this link http://postimage.org/image/4urmp716j/. This is the results I got based on your code. It looks different.

Comment: @MizukiKai I'm using OpenCV 2.4.3 rc.

Comment: I see. I'm using opencv 2.3.1 on windows. Weird. =)